# Why is ROWID data type represented as a character subtype - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldatatypes, rowid

As I searched, [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21901_01/timesten.1122/e21642/types.htm#TTSQL150) has a separate category for ROWID while in [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_data_types.htm) it categorizes it as a character subtype. As one can see in the Oracle Data Type page, the ROWID is indeed represented using characters. But why is it stored like a character type and not like a numeric one (especially integer) ? Are ROWIDs also stored as characters in the physical layer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that tutorialspoint is oversimplifying things a bit. It just *looks* like a character type when you're using it.

It's not stored like a character type. In fact, to do character operations on it (e.g. CONCAT) you have to cast it to a character type. As to why it's *represented* as a character type, it's probably just a good compromise of something that can be displayed in/copy-and-pasted from/typed into a SQL Query tool, but can store information more densely than a simple number. If it were just numeric digits, it would probably be quite long, given that it's an 80-bit number...

[A number encoded in base 64 using letters and numbers](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ROWID), which is what ROWID actually is, is a lot less unwieldy for a human being to deal with than a raw 10-byte number, in other words.

Answer (score 2):

It is stored as bytes, as everything else.

For example `'AAAACOAABAAAAR5AAA'` is stored as `00 00 00 8e 00 40 04 79 00 00`. But only in case you create and populate user column. `ROWID` that is selected using

```
SELECT ROWID FROM some_table
```

is not stored anywhere, it's physical address of the row in format:

object id, file number (for small file tablespaces), block number, block offset

ROWID elements are displayed in Base64 encoded form.